# Not able to change the Background color of Frame inside CollectionView in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, frame

I want to change the **background color of the Frame**. I tried many ways like **setting the Focused event, Triggers and Binding of background color property** nothing works for me. This is my xaml code.

```
<StackLayout Padding="10">
            <CollectionView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding samplelist}">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" HorizontalItemSpacing="10" VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">                        
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Frame  CornerRadius="10"  HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundTest,Mode=TwoWay}" HeightRequest="75" Margin="5,0,0,0" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference test}, Path=BindingContext.textselected}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

This my code in view model

```
private string _backgroundTest;
        public string BackgroundTest
        {
            get { return _backgroundTest; }
           
           // set => SetProperty(ref _backgroundTest, value);
            set
               {
                  if (value == _backgroundTest)
                       return;

                _backgroundTest = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundTest));
               }
        }
 private async void clicked(Test test)
        {
            BackgroundTest = "#F95F62";
}
```

I referred the following links
[How to change color of Frame control when clicked in Xamarin.Forms with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110085/how-to-change-color-of-frame-control-when-clicked-in-xamarin-forms-with-mvvm)

[Xamarin how to change background color on button click MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64310861/xamarin-how-to-change-background-color-on-button-click-mvvm?rq=1)

But nothing worked.I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: BackgroundColor expects a Color, but you are returning a string. Try using a Converter, or just use a Color property instead of a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackgroundColor expects a Color, but you are returning a string. Try using a Converter, or just use a Color property instead of a string

Option A: Use a [Value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert a string to Color (check the documentation)

- Create the converter class
- Add it to your App.Xaml
- Modify your Frame binding Xaml

  ```
  <Frame  CornerRadius="10"  HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundTest,Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" HeightRequest="75" Margin="5,0,0,0" >
  ```

Option B: Modify your binding to be a Color type

```
private Color _backgroundTest;
        public Color BackgroundTest
        {
            get { return _backgroundTest; }           
            set
               {
                  if (value == _backgroundTest)
                       return;

                _backgroundTest = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundTest));
               }
        }
 private async void clicked(Test test)
        {
            BackgroundTest = ColorConverters.FromHex("#F95F62");
}
```

---

**For both cases:**

In your code the BackgroundColor of the Frame is inside a CollectionView, so the binding will be looking for the property inside the Item. It should look it inside the ViewModel

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}},Path=BackgroundTest}"
```

Comment: Tried both not working.

Comment: I tested with a simpler XAML and it works fine. I checked the code again and the problem is that it's looking for the binding property inside the collectionview.Item. You will have to add a RelativeSource binding like `BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}},Path=BackgroundTest}"`

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks.